# Filtering within summarise function in r or summing previous rows based on filter - Reprex

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I'm trying to sum previous rows of data based on a filter of *name_ex* and a specified number of *rounds*. More specifically:

**Goal:** To sum the previous 3 rows of *stat1* and *stat2* respectively. These sums should only occur if the *name_ex* criteria is met. ie only sum *stat1* and *stat2* from Steve's rows (sum Steve's data, Bill's data, but avoid using Steve's data in Bill's.).

**Additional Goal:** Preferably, instead of summing just the last 3 rows, I would like to sum the rows of stat1 and stat2 based off a filter of rounds. Ie sum all the rounds up until rounds equals between 10 and 12. I'm not sure if this is achievable within a dplyr function or if I need to write a function to achieve it.

**Work:** I used the group_by function to get the data in it's desired form so I can use zoo to sum the last 3 rows of data.

**Issues:** My function solely calls the last 3 rows of data regardless of criteria. This is a problem because I'm not able to separate the data by each person's name (ie Bill pulls from Steve's). Additionally, I'm looking for a simplistic filter that pulls rows where name_ex criteria is met and rounds are between 10 and 12 (cumulatively).

[image: Desired Output]

```
#Load packages
library(dplyr)
library(tidyverse)
library(zoo)

#Reprex
name_ex <- c("steve", "steve","steve", "steve","steve","steve", "steve", "bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "bill", "john","john","john", "john","john","john", "john")
rounds <- c(4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2)
t_id <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4)
year <- c(2019, 2019,2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2020, 2020, 2020, 2020)
stat1 <- c(3.2, 3.4, -1.4, 2.1, 1.3, -1.7, -1.7, 1.1, 2.0, 1.3, .7, 1.5, 1.2, 2.5, 3.6, -1.1, 0.4, -1.2, -1.1, 1.6, 1.3, -2.7)
stat2 <- c(1.7, 1.2, 1.3, -.4, 1.1, 2.1, -2.1, .6, 1.1, 3.4, -1.1, -1.7, -1.3, 1.1, 2.4, 1.3, 2.6, .6, 1.3, .7, 2.3, -2.4)
event_n <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8)
test_df <- do.call(rbind, Map(data.frame, name_ex =name_ex, year = year, t_id = t_id, event_n = event_n, rounds =rounds, stat1 = stat1, stat2 = stat2))

#Sum the previous 3 columns of data for stat1 and stat2
test_df2 <- test_df %>%
  group_by(name_ex, t_id, year) 

test_df2$stat1_sum <- lag(rollsumr(test_df2$stat1, k = 3, fill = NA))
test_df2$stat2_sum <- lag(rollsumr(test_df2$stat2, k = 3, fill = NA))
test_df2

#bad attempt at filtering for name
#test_df2$stat1_sum <- lag(rollsumr(test_df2$stat1[name_ex == name_ex], k = 3, fill = NA))
```

Comment: "last 3 columns": do you mean rows?  Also, when you say "the last three rows", do you mean, for each value of x from 3 to 12, sum the rows between (x-3) and x, or just rows 10, 11 and 12?  if you could provide your *desrired* output, that would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @Limey. I will update the post to make it more clear. Yes, I meant the last 3 rows. The current code I wrote returns the desired result with the exception it pulls the last 3 rows regardless of name. I will follow up shortly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your first question can easily be answered using only `dplyr` if you first convert your data to long format.  (This also makes your data tidy.)

```
longDF <- test_df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("stat"),
    names_to="Statistic",
    values_to="Value"
  ) %>%
  arrange(Statistic, name_ex, year) %>%
  group_by(name_ex, Statistic) %>%
  mutate(
    ValueLag1=lag(Value),
    ValueLag2=lag(Value, 2)
  )
longDF
# A tibble: 44 × 9
# Groups:   name_ex, Statistic [6]
   name_ex  year  t_id event_n rounds Statistic Value ValueLag1 ValueLag2
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
 1 bill     2019     1       1      4 stat1       1.1      NA        NA  
 2 bill     2019     2       2      4 stat1       2         1.1      NA  
 3 bill     2019     3       3      4 stat1       1.3       2         1.1
 4 bill     2019     4       4      2 stat1       0.7       1.3       2  
 5 bill     2020     1       5      4 stat1       1.5       0.7       1.3
 6 bill     2020     2       6      2 stat1       1.2       1.5       0.7
 7 bill     2020     3       7      4 stat1       2.5       1.2       1.5
 8 bill     2020     4       8      2 stat1       3.6       2.5       1.2
 9 john     2019     1       1      4 stat1      -1.1      NA        NA  
10 john     2019     2       2      4 stat1       0.4      -1.1      NA  
# … with 34 more rows
```

The use of `group_by()` prevents one person's stats carrying over to the next person.  You can clearly see the effect in the output above.

Calculating the "sum of the last three" is now also simple:

```
longDF %>% 
  mutate(SumOfLastThree=Value + ValueLag1 + ValueLag2) %>% 
  select(-ValueLag1, -ValueLag2)
# A tibble: 44 × 8
# Groups:   name_ex, Statistic [6]
   name_ex  year  t_id event_n rounds Statistic Value SumOfLastThree
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>          <dbl>
 1 bill     2019     1       1      4 stat1       1.1           NA  
 2 bill     2019     2       2      4 stat1       2             NA  
 3 bill     2019     3       3      4 stat1       1.3            4.4
 4 bill     2019     4       4      2 stat1       0.7            4  
 5 bill     2020     1       5      4 stat1       1.5            3.5
 6 bill     2020     2       6      2 stat1       1.2            3.4
 7 bill     2020     3       7      4 stat1       2.5            5.2
 8 bill     2020     4       8      2 stat1       3.6            7.3
 9 john     2019     1       1      4 stat1      -1.1           NA  
10 john     2019     2       2      4 stat1       0.4           NA  
# … with 34 more rows
```

Does this give your expected output?

Consider

```
longDF %>% 
  mutate(
    CumulativeRounds=ifelse(
                       row_number() == 1, 
                       rounds, 
                       rounds+lag(rounds)
                     )
  )
# A tibble: 44 × 10
# Groups:   name_ex, Statistic [6]
   name_ex  year  t_id event_n rounds Statistic Value ValueLag1 ValueLag2 CumulativeRounds
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 bill     2019     1       1      4 stat1       1.1      NA        NA                  4
 2 bill     2019     2       2      4 stat1       2         1.1      NA                  8
 3 bill     2019     3       3      4 stat1       1.3       2         1.1                8
 4 bill     2019     4       4      2 stat1       0.7       1.3       2                  6
 5 bill     2020     1       5      4 stat1       1.5       0.7       1.3                6
 6 bill     2020     2       6      2 stat1       1.2       1.5       0.7                6
 7 bill     2020     3       7      4 stat1       2.5       1.2       1.5                6
 8 bill     2020     4       8      2 stat1       3.6       2.5       1.2                6
 9 john     2019     1       1      4 stat1      -1.1      NA        NA                  4
10 john     2019     2       2      4 stat1       0.4      -1.1      NA                  8
# … with 34 more rows
```

So

```
longDF %>% 
  select(-ValueLag1, -ValueLag2) %>% 
  mutate(
    CumulativeRounds=ifelse(
                       row_number() == 1, 
                       rounds, 
                       rounds+lag(rounds)
                     )
  ) %>% 
  filter(CumulativeRounds >= 8 & CumulativeRounds <= 10)
# A tibble: 22 × 8
# Groups:   name_ex, Statistic [6]
   name_ex  year  t_id event_n rounds Statistic Value CumulativeRounds
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>            <dbl>
 1 bill     2019     2       2      4 stat1       2                  8
 2 bill     2019     3       3      4 stat1       1.3                8
 3 john     2019     2       2      4 stat1       0.4                8
 4 john     2019     4       4      4 stat1      -1.2                8
 5 john     2020     1       5      4 stat1      -1.1                8
 6 john     2020     2       6      4 stat1       1.6                8
 7 john     2020     3       7      4 stat1       1.3                8
 8 steve    2019     2       2      4 stat1       3.4                8
 9 steve    2019     3       3      4 stat1      -1.4                8
10 steve    2020     3       7      4 stat1      -1.7                8
```

Is, I believe, what you want.

**Edit**

OP has now posted an image clarifying what they mean by "last three rows".  My suggested solutiuon for the first part of their problem can be easily adapted to produce the required results.

```
test_df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    starts_with("stat"),
    names_to="Statistic",
    values_to="Value"
  ) %>%
  arrange(Statistic, name_ex, year, t_id) %>%
  group_by(name_ex, Statistic) %>%
  mutate(
    ValueLag1=lag(Value),
    ValueLag2=lag(Value, 2),
    ValueLag3=lag(Value, 3),
    SumOfPreviousThree=ValueLag1 + ValueLag2 + ValueLag3
  ) %>% 
  select(-ValueLag1, -ValueLag2, -ValueLag3)
# A tibble: 44 × 8
# Groups:   name_ex, Statistic [6]
   name_ex  year  t_id event_n rounds Statistic Value SumOfPreviousThree
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>              <dbl>
 1 bill     2019     1       1      4 stat1       1.1               NA  
 2 bill     2019     2       2      4 stat1       2                 NA  
 3 bill     2019     3       3      4 stat1       1.3               NA  
 4 bill     2019     4       4      2 stat1       0.7                4.4
 5 bill     2020     1       5      4 stat1       1.5                4  
 6 bill     2020     2       6      2 stat1       1.2                3.5
 7 bill     2020     3       7      4 stat1       2.5                3.4
 8 bill     2020     4       8      2 stat1       3.6                5.2
 9 john     2019     1       1      4 stat1      -1.1               NA  
10 john     2019     2       2      4 stat1       0.4               NA  
# … with 34 more rows
```

To return to OP's untidy format, add the following to the end of the pipe:

```
%>% 
  pivot_wider(
    values_from=c(Value, SumOfPreviousThree),
    names_from=Statistic
  )
```

Comment: Wow @Limey. Mind blown that you were able to clean up the info that efficiently. This is an awesome solution.

Comment: I'm glad to have helped.  [Tidiness](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) is a very powerful concept.  It's worth investing some time to understand it, especially if you use the tidyverse.  It's the foundation on which the package is built.  A little time speant learning now will reap rich rewards later: just look at the knots you were tying yourself in compared to the clean solution I was able to provide.

Comment: Thanks @Limey - to be honest, I never considered turning the data into a long format to resolve my issue. I was thinking about it more from the perspective of how to apply in a ml format. I'm sure revisiting this area will have benefits with SQL and other programs as well. Cheers!